# Axios giving error: 404 (not found) with all the requests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm working in vuejs, and using axios. The axios is giving me the error **404 (not found)**. Banging my head around since 2 days and still cannot find the solution. The following is the code for axios and the error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you try from postman once check the endpoint is active?

Comment: i have checked it on the postman already, working fine there @saifali

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is missing either a scheme (`http://` or `https://`) or the double slash (`//`) that indicates it should be resolved relative to the current scheme.

Consequently, the IP address is taken as a relative **path** and the request is made to the same server for a path that doesn't exist.

You can see this in the error message that tells you the 404 error is coming from `http://localhost:8080/54.189.70.25/etc`!

Don't omit the scheme.

Comment: I have also worked on a similar project, everything seems to be working perfectly there, but, causing the trouble here. Can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: There's really nothing to elaborate on. It's a simple problem with a simple solution. I've no idea what is different with the other project.